# How to configure options for the Version Control's git commit command

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to options for the Version Control's git commit command? If so, how?
I'm a heavy user of the integrated source control UI in VS Code and I often need to provide extra options like `--no-verify` to the `git commit`. I still didn't figure out a way of doing this in VS Code.

Thanks!

Comment: I think your talking about [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to set `--no-verify` as a default, so you'd need to write your own [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) to do this, something like `git config --global alias.mycommit 'commit --no-verify'`

Comment: @Liam thanks for your reply. How can I make that alias my default commit command in VS Code?

Comment: You cant. Why does it make a difference? `git commit` vs `git mycommit`?

Comment: The point is to be able to use VS Code user interface instead of having to drop to the shell every time I need to do a commit. Thanks nevertheless @Liam!

Comment: [VSCode is open source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) so you could add a feature request for this and see if anyone else wants it. Though this seems a bit niche to me. I don't think there is anything in VSCode that will handle this currently.

Comment: just posted this in the github issues. thumb it up if you're still interested in it https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110452

Comment: Commit --no-verify will be in VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020). See [my updated answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63965747/6309)

Answer (score 22):

With VSCode 1.50 (Sept 2020), there should now be more option for `git commit` in VSCode.

See [PR 106335](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/106335): Adds commands for `--no-verify` commit variants

> This PR adds `*NoVerify` command variants for creating commits while skipping pre-commit and commit-msg hooks.
>
> The commands are only displayed if the `git.allowNoVerifyCommit` option is set to true.
> This type of commits requires additional confirmation (like `git.pushForce` does), which can be bypassed by disabling the `git.confirmNoVerifyCommit` option.

[image: https://camo.githubusercontent.com/5c42dec32f31c5083e24299459693d5c9e5c9579/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f585138304c57592e706e67]

---

As illustrated with [issue 110452](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110452#event-3987751212), `commit --no-verify` will be in VSCode 1.52 (Nov. 2020)

> Once you enable `git.allowNoVerifyCommit`, a bunch of commands will be available:
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22350/98923649-38d3bf80-24d4-11eb-955a-5c9560dfbf76.png]

That means opening the settings: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>, that will update the VSCode `settings.json`.

Comment: They deleted this functionality as of today (March 2023)? I do not find any option to add the `--no-verify` tag!!

Comment: @joangm_ I do see that option, but only if I activate the setting `git.allowNoVerifyCommit`.

Comment: Oh, yes! It worked! Thank you very much! For people wondering, you have to add that line in `settings.json` of the VSCode.

Comment: @joangm_ True. I have edited the answer to include the shortcut to open VSCode settings.